# I use NSJSONSerialization in my app, can this app function well under IOS 3.x?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I am a newbie in IOS development, and my app use the class NSJSONSerialization to parse JSON data from the configuration file.

now my question is, can this app function well under the version IOS 3.x ? by the way, the NSJSONSerialization is a new class in IOS 5.0.

because my iphone3GS was broken , I can't test it now.

Comment: What do you think? You've said yourself the class is new in iOS5, so why would you expect it to work in iOS3?

Comment: Apple only writes this availability stuff in order to encourage people buying new products. In reality they didn't do anything since the first iPhone. So everything will work. Now and in the future. - Do you really mean this question honest? Of course, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's an API that is only available in iOS 5+.  So, no, it will break on iOS 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @pbx I was going to put in the versions before 0 too but it would have taken all day and I still would not be finished :)